# Firebase Realtime database getvalue() not mapping the object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase chat structure(see image below). I want to get only amitpal_name value not the others but this method fetching me all the values
I had also use this

[image]

`dbreference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "ChatMessage" ).child( "msg");`

```
    dbreference.orderByChild("Ref").addChildEventListener( new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
           Iterator iterator=dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                String chatis=(String) ((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue();
                Log.e( "ADDED IS-" , chatis);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Iterator iterator=dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                String chatis=(String) ((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue();
                Log.e( "ADDED chng-" , chatis);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e( "ERRO FBDB-", databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    } );
```

**dbreference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "ChatMessage" ).child( "msg").child("amitpal_name");**

but it not providing any info or values pls help me here

I have also try this below method giving me good and expected result but the main problem is i want to reflect the new value in listview when databse update in firebaserealtime Chat without using service, for that i need this method below

**public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)**

Comment: did you try ref like this dbreference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatMessage" ).child( "msg").child("amitpal_name");

Comment: yes i writed it above i am using this but it didnt providing me anything no value

Comment: haha i know i read that. please notice getReference() has no parameters

Comment: not working tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your reference

```
    refAmitPat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatMessage").child("msg");
```

and here is child event listner on your DB Reference

```
refAmitPat.child("amitpal_name").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d("amitPal",dataSnapshot.getValue()+"");
                // add message value to list and call notify datasetchange method 
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d("amitPal",dataSnapshot.getValue()+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

what are you doing, wrong is, you are iterating the datasnapshot whereas when you push the message under usernames as child, the child will get as the datasnapshot in childAdded method, means the data snapshot your are iterating, is actually your message with push-key and message value. so there's no need to iterate through that. simply call datasnapshot.getValue() function to get message value

Answer (score 1):

change your below line

```
String chatis=(String) ((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue();
```

to

```
String chatis=((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue().toString();
```

Updated method below

```
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
Log.e( "OUTER ADDED IS-" , dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
       Iterator iterator=dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
        DataSnapshot local = (DataSnapshot) iterator.next();
            String chatis=local.getValue().toString();
            Log.e( "Inner ADDED IS-" , chatis);
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

also below line as well after the reference initialization

```
dbreference.keepSynced(true);
```

Comment: yes i tried it but it is giving me value when i use  dbreference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "ChatMessage" ).child( "msg") not when dbreference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "ChatMessage" ).child( "msg").child("amitpal_name");

Comment: what do you want??

Comment: i want the amitpal_name value only not the other one

Comment: @SunilChaudhary Where does it break ?? As i can see **amitpal_name** is having multiple values. Do you want to read all of them?

Comment: yes i want all the value it didnt break but also not providing anything after using dbreference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "ChatMessage" ).child( "msg").child("amitpal_name")

Comment: @SunilChaudhary let me know what is the outer value you are getting?? while using **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "ChatMessage" ).child( "msg").child("amitpal_name") ;**

Comment: when i use this dbreference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "ChatMessage" ).child( "msg").child("amitpal_name") i am not getting any value

Comment: Do you put log as i mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: @SunilChaudhary Also check if you are getting error in the above case under **onCancelled** method

Comment: Ok. try to add **ValueEventListener** as well and put log inside **onCancelled** method of the same

Comment: ValueEventListener yes i  already used it and it is giving me the right answer  but the main problem is that i want to reflect the chat in the receiver side without refreshing the activity are u getting me

Comment: i have to refresh it first and then the data is showing in listview but i want that without refreshing and for that i want DataChangeListner thats why i asking this question here thnx

Comment: @SunilChaudhary a question: What do you mean by refreshing it? Meaning go to back another screen and then came back?

Comment: OnResume() method

Comment: Ok. can you post onResume method code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

check the answer for this post this may help:
[I want to list all unique childrens and keys along with values in a spinner firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499322/i-want-to-list-all-unique-childrens-and-keys-along-with-values-in-a-spinner-fire)

In this, you can see how to fetch each of the node values then key along with their values.

```
 mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

         //"It will give you all node values:"+dataSnapshot.getKey()
        //"You can check ": 

          if(dataSnapshot.getKey()=="amitpal"){
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot2 : childDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

         // "CHILD KEY"+childDataSnapshot2.getKey()

                arrayList.add(childDataSnapshot2.getKey());

         //"CHILD VALUES"+childDataSnapshot2.getValue()

            }}

            }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I have given clarification, sorry for capital letters. Thanks for telling that.

Comment: you're welcome. (if seen.. flag mine for removal and remove yours as well so we stop the clutter ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatMessage" ).child( "msg").child("amitpal_name");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onDataChange ( @NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2){
    }
}
```