# firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase

[database structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7OWZ.png)

I getting this error say

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while
>   deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList

I try some solution from [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016979/firebase-realtime-database-getvalue-not-mapping-the-object) [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844121/firebase-database-exception-while-retrieving-data-from-firebase-database) and more, plus some googling for hours but i didn't get any working solution.

so please anyone can help me to understanding this firebase structure [database structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7OWZ.png) and its solution.

here is my sample code

category object class

```
public class Category {
    private String link;
    private String categoryName;
    private String activeJob;
    private Map<String, JobList> jobList;

    ....

    public Map<String, JobList> getJobList() {
        return jobList;
    }

    public void setJobList(Map<String, JobList> jobList) {
        this.jobList = jobList;
    }
}
```

Job list object class

```
public class JobList {
    private String employerName;
    private String jobClosingDate;
    private String jobCode;
    private String jobTitle;
    private String jobLink;
    private String status;
    private String updatedDate;
```

at MainActivity

```
public void getJobListFromFirebase() {
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                categories = dataSnapshot.getValue(Category.class);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }
            .......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `category` class to this:

```
    private String link;
    private String categoryName;
    private String activeJob;
    private List<JobList> jobList;

    ....

    public List<JobList> getJobList() {
        return jobList;
    }

    public void setJobList(List<JobList> jobList) {
        this.jobList = jobList;
    }
}
```

from your database structure, either we can do something like `List<JobList>` or `Map<Int,JobList>` (not `Map<String,JobList>`). 
try this and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much it working : ) can you please tell me why it work with list and not arrayList?

Comment: arrayList will also work... but not `map<string,JobList>`

Answer (score 0):

change Map of jobList to List of joblist in Category model class

```
public class Category {
    private String link;
    private String categoryName;
    private String activeJob;
    private List<JobList> jobList;

    ....

    public List<JobList> getJobList() {
        return jobList;
    }

    public void setJobList(List<JobList> jobList) {
        this.jobList = jobList;
    }
}
```